# Inequality in a number theory Math Olympiad problem?!

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, solution-verification, contest-math

### Prove $\sum_{cyc}(ab) + \sum_{cyc}(a) \le abc$ where $a,b$ and $c$ are distinct odd primes.

I was doing this number theory problem from APMO (?) ;

Are there distinct prime numbers $a, b, c$ which satisfy $ a \mid bc+b+c \ ,\ b \mid ca+c+a\ ,\ c \mid ab+a+b$?

In my solution [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2530811p21511300) , I used the fact that $\sum_{cyc}ab + \sum_{cyc}a \le abc$ where $a,b$ and $c$ are distinct odd primes.

But my proof and reasoning seemed a little 'non - rigorous' to me, I said that the inequality we need to prove is equivalent to :

$\sum_{cyc}(\frac{1}{a}) + \sum_{cyc}(\frac{1}{ab}) \le 1$ ,

Now if I let the expression equal to $g(a,b,c)$ , then clearly maximum of $g$ occurs at $(3,5,7)$, but $g(a,b,c) = 86/105 < 1$ so our original inequality is proved.

Could you please tell me if this is a valid proof, my main problem is in saying "clearly maximum of $g$ occurs at $(3,5,7)$, but $g(a,b,c) = 86/105 < 1$" cause that doesn't seem rigorous.

Thanks!

Comment: I mean, you can provide more explanation for why it attains its maximum at $(3,5,7)$. You can restrict $g$ to a function of odd primes $(a,b,c)$ with $a<b<c$, then you can show the function is decreasing in all three variables... But depending on your reader, what you said seems fine to me.

Comment: @runway44 , Thank you so much!

Comment: Which book do you use for Olympiad prep , @Aditya_math ?

Comment: @Sukhoi234 this was from MONT by Aditya Khurmi